# Testing if an event has been triggered in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, eventemitter

In the project we are building, there is a standard sequence in the workflow.

1. Controller receives a request
2. Then fires an event through @nestjs/event-emitter
3. Event listener listens to it and executes some code depending on the event

How can we properly test if an event has been triggered but without actually executing the code inside?

We are using Jest for testing.

Mocking with Jest doesn't seem to work, because we want to test the actual trigger event and not the result.

Any suggestions?

```
"node": "16.14.2"
"@nestjs/event-emitter": "^1.1.0",
"jest": "^27.5.1",
```

Comment: Could you please add the code to show what have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to spy on the handler method that listens to the event or alternatively spy on the encapsulated methods that get called within it. Once your spies are set up you should then be able to trigger the event emitter code from your test and validate if the spies have been triggered.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! I posted the test below as an example if someone is having the same issue

Answer (score 5):

Following the suggestion from @ovidijus-parsiunas we managed to spy on the "OnEvent" method successfully.

```
it.only("start selling", async () => {
    const user = await userSeeder.createOne();

    const spy = jest
      .spyOn(StartSellingListener.prototype, 'startSelling')
      .mockImplementation(() => null);

    expect(eventEmitter.hasListeners(EventsEnum.USER_START_SELLING)).toBe(true);

    const startSelling = userService.startSelling(user);
    expect(startSelling).toBeTruthy();

    expect(spy).toBeCalledWith(user);

    spy.mockRestore();
  });
```

Comment: Can you show how you initialized your testing module? My registered events don't get added to the listeners.